# Yield curve steepening/flattening using different duration treasury futures (TUT Spread) and volatility

Tags: volatility, portfolio-management, futures, yield-curve, bond-futures

Yield curve steepening: long 2 contracts 2 year (2 contracts due to contract size), short 1 contract 10 year
Vice versa for flattening.

If the 2 year note has a expected volatility of 2% per contract (or 4% for 2 contracts) and the 10 year has a expected volatility of 6%, how can i calculate the expected volatility of this spread?

Comment: "how can i calculate the expected volatility of this spread?" - why not just look at the realised vol of the PNL for your given ratio? (which is not DV01-neutral). There are other ways to do it but this might be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to define what you mean by "expected volatility". Once you formulate formally the expected volatility, then I presume you will get the answer yourself.